# Dynamic Multilingual website with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, dom

I'm trying to dynamically change the language of a website depending of the user browser language.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MultiLingual</title>
    <style>
        button {
            font-size: 30px;
            padding: 0.25 2rem;
            margin: 1rem;
            width: 10rem;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        [lang="en-CA"] {
            border: 5px solid #dd0000;
            margin: 1rem;
        }

        [lang="fr-CA"] {
            border: 5px solid limegreen;
            margin: 1rem;
        }

        [lang="es-ES"] {
            border: 5px solid gold;
            margin: 1rem;
        }

        div[lang] {
            display: none;
        }

        div[lang].lang-match {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div lang="en-CA">
        <button data-key="btn-yes">Actual</button>
        <button data-key="btn-no">Actual</button>
    </div>
    <div lang="es-ES">
        <button data-key="btn-yes">DEFAULT</button>
        <button data-key="btn-no">DEFAULT</button>
    </div>
    <div lang="fr-CA">
        <button data-key="btn-yes">DEFAULT</button>
        <button data-key="btn-no">DEFAULT</button>
    </div>

    <script>

        let langdata = {
            "languages": {
                "en": {
                    "strings": {
                        "btn-yes": "yes",
                        "btn-no": "no"
                    }
                },
                "fr": {
                    "strings": {
                        "btn-yes": "oui",
                        "btn-no": "non"
                    }
                },
                "es": {
                    "strings": {
                        "btn-yes": "si",
                        "btn-no": "no"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        //apply the language values to the content
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    
            let zones = document.querySelectorAll('html [lang]');
            applyStrings(zones);

            let lang = findLocaleMatch();
            let container = document.querySelector(`html [lang*=${lang}]`);
            container.className = 'lang-match';
        });

        function applyStrings(containers) {
            containers.forEach(container => {
                //find all the elements that have data-key
                let locale = container.getAttribute('lang');
                
                container.querySelectorAll(`[data-key]`).forEach(element => {
                    let key = element.getAttribute('data-key');
 
                    let lang = locale.substr(0, 2); //first 2 characters
                    if (key) {
                        element.textContent = langdata.languages[lang].strings[key];
                    }
                });
            })
        }

        function findLocaleMatch() {
            let keys = Object.keys(langdata.languages); //from our data
            let locales = Intl.getCanonicalLocales(keys); //from our data validated

            let lang = navigator.language; //from browser 
            let locale = Intl.getCanonicalLocales(lang); //from browser validated
            console.log('browser language', lang);
            console.log('locales from data file', locale);

            //find the match for locale inside locales
            let langMatch = document.documentElement.getAttribute('lang'); //default
            locales = locales.filter(l => locale == l); 
            langMatch = (locales.length > 0) ? locales[0] : langMatch;
            return langMatch;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've been trying the code by changing the browser language and it works for english and french. However when I change to Spanish, it displays the English content.

I don't know where is the issue, trying to figure out.

Hope someone can help,

Comment: It works for me on Chrome. Settings > Advanced > Languages > Spanish > move to top > refresh page. I then see the button text is in spanish. `findLocaleMatch()` returns "es" for me.

Comment: In the console check to see what the output of `findLocaleMatch()` is.

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, I encourage you to use this instead: https://www.i18next.com/overview/getting-started. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @dwosk it returns "es" but can you see the buttons in spanish? Or instead you see buttons in english?

Comment: @JFelix I see the buttons in spanish

Comment: well, I see in spanish just in Safari. I tried in different devices and sometimes the content is in english and another times in spanish. It's so weird

Comment: Did you change the country to Spain as well (España for `es-ES` to work)?
Did you try your code without the `-ES`, just `es`?
May I suggest not forcing the viewer to a language, and, instead, offer a "Change Language" button with drop-down options where you can list those that you currently support?  Perhaps with a familiar globe icon.  What about right-to-left, up-down, sideways (joking) language direction and HTML rendering (`dir` attribute)?

Comment: @iAmOren I finally made it. I also as you suggested, added a button with the languages option, thank you!

Comment: Excellent!
Glad to be of assistance!
What was the problem?
What did you change?
Can I see the site?